# Why does my main tab code give "run-time error '9' when clicking on cell that goes to website?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has about 350 tabs in it. Other than the main page they are all hidden. I have the following code for the main tab which allows me to click on links from that main tab that will temporarily open the hidden tab and then when you click off of it; it goes hidden again.

```
'=========>>
Option Explicit

Dim bFlag As Boolean

'--------->>
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant

    If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
    arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")
    Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))
    SH.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    bFlag = True
    Target.Follow
    bFlag = False
End Sub
```

'<<=========

It works flawless for me. Within those hidden tabs I can have cells that link out to external web pages etc and they open and work fine. On those 350 tabs they have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

End Sub

'--------->>
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Me.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
'<<=========
```

Again, it all works the way it's supposed to. The problem I have is on that main page I mentioned above if I try to create a cell with a link that references a webpage outside the workbook it opens fine; but gives me that beautiful "run-time error '9'. Subscript out of range.

Is there something in my main tab code I screwed up that its only looking to do things within the workbook itself?

Comment: This is not JavaScript code. Seems like Visual Basic but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is visual basic in excel. I apologize, I tagged the wrong section; I just edited and fixed it. Again, my apology....I was just typing to quickly.

Comment: Again not VBScript, have retagged.

Comment: When following a hyperlink to a web page `Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))` will fail, as `arr(0)` will not be the name of a sheet. You'll need to test `Subaddress` to see if it's a range or a URL

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink) on Hyperlink objects in Excel isn't very detailed. As far as I can tell from creating some different hyperlinks:

Hyperlinks to cells within a workbook have the `Address` property contain an empty string and the `SubAddress` property contain the address of the linked cell (e.g. "Sheet2!A1")

Hyperlinks to webpages have the `Address` property contain the URL of the webpage and the `SubAddress` property contain an empty string.

To correct the issue with your code, you could check that the `SubAddress` is not empty immediately before the `arr = Split` line, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant

    If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
    If Target.SubAddress = "" Then Exit Sub

    arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Still haven't figured out a great solution for this. It's the fact that my main excel page has links that reference other tabs within the workbook but also have cells that reference hyperlinks out to websites. I've tried multiple ways to try to make this work and continue to get that error message.

Comment: Did adding the `If Target.SubAddress = "" Then Exit Sub` line not make any difference?